# Using JSON with VB.NET ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

Total newby question here, I've been struggling with it for hours!

I'm trying to understand how to actually use, and create JSON data. I've been Googling all afternoon and trying to understand what I fine here http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ having downloaded the Newtonsoft DLLs.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("CPU");
jsonWriter.WriteValue("Intel");
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("PSU");
jsonWriter.WriteValue("500W");
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Drives");
jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
jsonWriter.WriteValue("DVD read/writer");
jsonWriter.WriteComment("(broken)");
jsonWriter.WriteValue("500 gigabyte hard drive");
jsonWriter.WriteValue("200 gigabype hard drive");
jsonWriter.WriteEnd();
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Should create something that looks like:

```
{
   "CPU": "Intel",
   "PSU": "500W",
   "Drives": [
   "DVD read/writer"
    /*(broken)*/,
     "500 gigabyte hard drive",
     "200 gigabype hard drive"      ]
}
```

and I am sure it does... but how do I view it? How do I turn that into an object that the browser can output.

It seems to me that the first stage I need to resolve is "how to create" JSON files/strings, next stage will be how to actually use them. If it helps answer the question, what I'm aiming for initially is to be able to use AJAX Autocomplete from a search page generated from my MySQL database, I was hoping I could write a simple SQL query and have that returned using something similar to the above, but I'm clearly going about it all wrong!

BTW, the example above is in C#, I have successfully converted the process to VB, as that's what I am using, but any responses would be much appreciated as VB examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post about two years after it was posted, but I had the exact same question and noticed that the question wasn't really answered. To answer OP's question, this will get you the JSON string in his example.

```
sb.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The upshot is that you need to get the JSON string back to the browser. You can either place it in a javascript variable (be sure to clean up line enders and single quotes if you do this) or pass it back as the result of an ajax query.

We actually use the built-in Javascript serializer since it has support both on the server and the client side and is quite easy to use. Assuming that you have an existing object, this code goes on the server side:

```
''' <summary>
''' This method safely serializes an object for JSON by removing all of the special characters (i.e. CRLFs, quotes, etc)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="oObject"></param>
''' <param name="fForScript">Set this to true when the JSON will be embedded directly in web page (as opposed to being passed through an ajax call)</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function SerializeObjectForJSON(ByVal oObject As Object, Optional ByVal fForScript As Boolean = False) As String

If oObject IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim sValue As String

    sValue = (New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer).Serialize(oObject)

    If fForScript Then
        ' If this serialized object is being placed directly on the page, then we need to ensure that its CRLFs are not interpreted literlally (i.e. as the actual JS values)
        ' If we don't do this, the script will not deserialize correctly if there are any embedded crlfs.
        sValue = sValue.Replace("\r\n", "\\r\\n")

        ' Fix quote marks
        Return CleanString(sValue)
    Else
        Return sValue
    End If
Else
    Return String.Empty
End If
End Function
```

On the client side, deserialization is trivial:

```
    // The result should be a json-serialized record
    oRecord = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result.value);
```

Once you have deserialized the object, you can use its properties directly in javascript:

```
alert('CPU = ' + oRecord.CPU);
```

Comment: Thanks @ competent_tech handy info. That's helped cleared up what the process I am trying to deal with actually is, and I have now managed to get a JSON output from my code above. The deserialization bit won't work though, getting all kinds of errors and whatever I change does not fix it! I'm thinking this is because I am using .NET 2.0 and VB, Googling just gets me C# examples and I'm not 100% convinced of how well the built-in Serializer is supported with .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

In terms of generating the JSON try

```
    public class HardwareInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CPU")]
        public string Cpu { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PSU")]
        public string Psu { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public ICollection<string> Drives { get; set; }
    }

    public string SerializeHardwareInfo()
    {
        var info = new HardwareInfo
        {
            Cpu = "Intel",
            Psu = "500W",
            Drives = new List<string> { "DVD read/writer", "500 gigabyte hard drive", "200 gigabype hard drive" }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info, Formatting.Indented);
        //  {
        //    "CPU": "Intel",
        //    "PSU": "500W",
        //    "Drives": [
        //      "DVD read/writer",
        //      "500 gigabyte hard drive",
        //      "200 gigabype hard drive"
        //    ]
        //  }
        return json;
    }
```

The formatting argument is optional.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of looks simpler, except I am using VB, but I guess it's easy enough to alter for VB. I have finally managed to get my initial example to generate JSON, but now am stuggling with doing anything with it! See my comment on competent_tech's post below